# insert DateTimePicker data in phpmyadmin

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, database

I'd like the user to book their appointment through the form. I used the datetimepicker jquery as follows:

```
<script src="jquery.js"></script>
<script src="jquery.datetimepicker.js"></script>
<script>
 $(function() {
     jQuery('#DateTime').datetimepicker({
        format:'D, d M Y H:i',

        });
    });
</script>
```

Previously i used the datepicker and i successfully inserted the data into the table. After changing to datetimepicker jquery and data type as datetime, i faced with a problem on inserting the data. I've tried the solutions but it still failed. My codes are as follows:

```
if (! $conn)

    die("Couldn't connect to MySQL");

$query = "SELECT from Client (Client_ID)";  

$sql = "INSERT INTO Appointment (Client_ID,Svc_ID,Appt_DateTime) 
VALUES ('$_POST[ClientID]','$_POST[ApptType]','$_POST[DateTime]')";


mysql_query($query,$sql,$conn);

dbDisconnect($conn);
```

Comment: Do you get any errors? Also, what's the value of `$_POST[DateTime]`?

Comment: `datetime` datatype need date format `YYYY-MM-DD H:i:s`

Comment: this code is suseptible to SQL Injection

Comment: What is `mysql_query($query,$sql,$conn);`? `mysql_query()` takes only 2 parameters - [`mysql_query ( string $query [, resource $link_identifier = NULL ] )`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php)

Comment: **Danger**: You are using [an **obsolete** database API](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12859942/19068) and should use a [modern replacement](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php).  You are also **vulnerable to [SQL injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com/)** that a modern API would make it easier to [defend](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/best-way-to-prevent-sql-injection-in-php) yourself from.

Comment: You aren't looking at the return value of `mysql_query`. You aren't calling `mysql_error`. You need to learn the basics of the APIs you use so you can find out what is going wrong when you use them.

Comment: @ekad I did not get any errors just that data is could not be inserted in the database. The value of $_POST[DateTime] is the value client would see when they select a date to book appointment as follows (Mon, 20 Nov 2014 1500)

Comment: @GBD the datetime appears as follows: jQuery('#DateTime').datetimepicker({
        format:'D, d M Y H:i',                                        is what the client will see on the site. so where could i add the codes to format it according to phpmyadmin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this works fine

```
 "INSERT INTO Appointment (Client_ID,Svc_ID,Appt_DateTime) 
VALUES ('$_POST[ClientID]','$_POST[ApptType]','".date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime($_POST[DateTime]))."')");
```